# Puppet conditional check between vagrant & ec2

Tags: amazon-ec2, puppet, vagrant

I've looked at the documentation for [puppet variables](http://docs.puppetlabs.com/guides/language_guide.html#variables) and can't seem to get my head around how to apply this to the following situation:

```
if vagrant (local machine)

phpfpm::nginx::vhost { 'vhost_name':
    server_name => 'dev.demo.com',
    root        => '/vagrant/public',
}

else if aws ec2 (remote machine)

phpfpm::nginx::vhost { 'vhost_name':
    server_name => 'demo.com',
    root        => '/home/ubuntu/demo.com/public',
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try running facter on both your vagrant host and your EC2 instance, and look for differences. I suspect that 'facter virtual' may be different between the two hosts, or that the EC2 may return a bunch of ec2_ facts that won't be present on the vagrant host.

Then you can use this fact as a top level variable as per below.  I switched to a case statement as well, since that's a little easier to maintain IMHO, plus you can use the default block for error checking.

```
case $::virtual {
  'whatever vagrant returns' : {
    <vagrant specific provisionin>
   }
  'whatever the EC2 instance returns' : {
     <EC2 specific provisioning>
   }
   default : {
      fail("Unexpected virtual value of $::virtual")
   }
}
```

Comment: Great thanks, yes virtual responded with virtualbox for vagrant and physical for ec2 : )

Answer (score 5):

NOTE: In the three years since this response was posted, Vagrant has introduced the `facter` hash option. See @thomas' answer below for more details. I believe that this is the right way to go and makes my proposed kernel command line trick pretty obsolete. The rationale for using a fact hasn't changed, though, only strengthened (e.g. Vagrant currently supports AWS provider).

ORIGINAL REPLY: Be careful - you assume that you only use virtualbox for vagrant and vice versa, but Vagrant is working on support for other virtualization technologies (e.g. kvm), and you might use VirtualBox without vagrant one day (e.g. for production).

Instead, the trick I use is to pass the kernel a "vagrant=yes" parameter when I build the basebox, which is then accessible via /proc/cmdline. Then you can create a new fact based on that (e.g. /etc/vagrant file and check for it in subsequent facter runs).

Answer (score 3):

Vagrant has a [great utility for providing Puppet facts](http://docs.vagrantup.com/v2/provisioning/puppet_apply.html):

> facter (hash) - A hash of data to set as available facter variables
>   within the Puppet run.

For example, here's a snippet from my Vagrantfile with the Puppet setup:

```
config.vm.provision "puppet", :options => ["--fileserverconfig=/vagrant/fileserver.conf"]  do |puppet|
    puppet.manifests_path = "./"
    puppet.module_path = "~/projects/puppet/modules"
    puppet.manifest_file  = "./vplan-host.pp"
    puppet.facter = {
      "vagrant_puppet_run" => "true"
    }
  end
```

And then we make use of that fact for example like this:

```
  $unbound_conf = $::vagrant_puppet_run ? {
    'true'  => 'puppet:///modules/unbound_dns/etc/unbound/unbound.conf.vagrant',
    default => 'puppet:///modules/unbound_dns/etc/unbound/unbound.conf',
  }

  file { '/etc/unbound/unbound.conf':
    owner  => root,
    group  => root,
    notify => Service['unbound'],
    source => $unbound_conf,
  }
```

Note that the fact is only available during `puppet provision` time.